# Sylow 5-subgroups of groups of order $2^n5^m$ are normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My textbook says:

Show that a group of order $2^n5^m, m, n \ge 1$ has a normal 5-Sylow subgroup.

I've been banging my head against this problem for days with no success, how can I prove this?

Comment: I would be quite surprised if this were true actually! Where does the question come from?

Comment: For instance $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf C_2^n) = \mathsf{GL}_n(2)$ will surely have an element of order $5$ at some point and I would think that the corresponding semi-direct product $(\mathbf C_2)^n\rtimes\mathbf C_5$ is a counter-example.

Comment: @Myself That would be something like $C_2^5\rtimes C_5$, the action being rotation of the coordinates. But that is no counterexample.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes I meant: "is sometimes a counterexample" :-) It's just a guess. Btw in the case you cite, how do you know immediately that $C_5$ is normal?

Comment: It's exercise 18 in Section 5.6 of Algebra: Abstract and Concrete by Frederick Goodman, available for free download at http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/algebrabook.dir/download.htm.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I disagree. $C_2^5 \rtimes C_5$ does not have a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup, so it is a counterexample. I am afraid that this exercise is just wrong. It is true for $n \le 3$, but false for $n \ge 4$.

Comment: The question is stated in https://books.google.co.in/books?id=H3maAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA268&dq=Show+that+a+group+of+order+2n5m,m,n%E2%89%A51+has+a+normal+5-Sylow+subgroup&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sQG1VLHiKtWiugSX74HIBg&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Show%20that%20a%20group%20of%20order%202n5m%2Cm%2Cn%E2%89%A51%20has%20a%20normal%205-Sylow%20subgroup&f=false; but many comments are giving counterexample. I don't see what is missing.